# На одностаничнике сделать свап с перекидыванием кнопки управления?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css-animation

У меня есть концепция сайта и я не могу придумать в силу не опытности как её реализовать.
Задача в том, чтобы на сайте было 2 секции.
1я - с которой сайт стартует.
2я - при нажатии на кнопку в углу, происходила анимация свайпа страницы и появлялся как бы 2й лист сайта, который находился позади.

Я примерно понял как это можно реализовать, но со свайпом в бок и без ярлычка
(при попытки такое реализовать Up to Down, секция просто смещается, а не исчезает)

Реализовать ярлычок, который разворачивался бы на 180, а также свайп сверху вниз у меня не получилось.

Как возможно сделать ярлычок сверху при вытягивании которого появлялась бы секция позади, а ярлычок переворачивался чтобы была возможность вернуться ?

```html
 <section class="showcase">
    <header>
      <h2 class="logo">Title</h2>
      <div class="toggle"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </section>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Destination</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
header .logo
{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle
{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle.active
{
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.showcase
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
  right: 80%;
}
.overlay
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #03a9f4;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
.menu
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu ul
{
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul li
{
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #111;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
  color: #03a9f4; 
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
{
  .showcase,
  .showcase header
  {
    padding: 40px;
  }
}
```

```js
 const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
      const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

      menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
        showcase.classList.toggle('active');
      })
```

Comment: если проблема в таче, то вот дока https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понимаю реализацию, но у меня есть пример кода:

`script.js`

```
const body = document.body
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
const leftBtn = document.getElementById('left')
const rightBtn = document.getElementById('right')

let activeSlide = 0

rightBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeSlide++

  if (activeSlide > slides.length - 1) {
    activeSlide = 0
  }

  setBgToBody()
  setActiveSlide()
})

leftBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeSlide--

  if (activeSlide < 0) {
    activeSlide = slides.length - 1
  }

  setBgToBody()
  setActiveSlide()
})

setBgToBody()

function setBgToBody() {
  body.style.backgroundImage = slides[activeSlide].style.backgroundImage
}

function setActiveSlide() {
  slides.forEach((slide) => slide.classList.remove('active'))

  slides[activeSlide].classList.add('active')
}
```

`style.css`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider-container {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  height: 70vh;
  width: 70vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15vh;
  left: -15vw;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: calc(15vw - 65px);
}

.right-arrow {
  right: calc(15vw - 65px);
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Background Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slide active" style="
          background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80');
        "></div>
    <div class="slide" style="
          background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511593358241-7eea1f3c84e5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80');
        "></div>

    <div class="slide" style="
          background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495467033336-2effd8753d51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80');
        "></div>

    <div class="slide" style="
          background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522735338363-cc7313be0ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2689&q=80');
        "></div>

    <div class="slide" style="
          background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559087867-ce4c91325525?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80');
        "></div>

    <button class="arrow left-arrow" id="left">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
      </button>

    <button class="arrow right-arrow" id="right">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </button>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```